# AsyncTask OnPostExecute not updating TextView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I have an `AsyncTask` running. I have a `TextView` that I mimic the message a `Toast` initially produces.
I want to clear the `TextView` upon success in `OnPostExecute` but it not doing so. The task complete `Toast` works fine. How do I set the `TextView` in the `OnPostExecute` to blank? The user is still on the display screen where the `TextView` is.

Code is as follows for an error condition:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
 { FetchingImage=0;
  if(webLoadError>0)
   {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String temp=" ";
    text.setText(temp);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not available from the internet.\nDefault or last image loaded.\nTry again later.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("");
```

**EDIT:**

try making a variable outside the `onCreate` like `TextView text;` and then inside the `onCreate` put: `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);`

and then just put `text.setText("");` inside the `onPostExecute` method.

See if that works.

Comment: Well, then I don't know what could be causing the texview to not clear. All I could think of is check that the id of the texview that you want to clear is the one that you want to clear, you are probably clearing another texview and not knowing.

Comment: Its the same one that I put text into before I call the asynch task. SO the ID is correct. I'm trying using GONE and make visible and that kinda seems to work but seems clumsy way of doing it.   TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
TextView iv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: That would make the text view disappear, it will not clear it. I did not think you wanted that.

Comment: No I wanted the text in the text view to clear. Which is  not happening. You suggested I was calling the wrong one which I am not. I dont want to have to destroy the text view and recreate it just to clear it. So I am still looking for a solution to clear it. Its like the setText is not executing. Cause if I can destroy the object using the same findviewById... still looking. thanks for the extra brain cells.

Comment: Eclipse needed a CLEAN project. After I did that the goofiness went away and both methods worked. I like your more concise instruction. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't access the ```text``` inside onPostExecute, since the AsyncTask is static.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I think I found the solution (at least it worked for me), perhaps it help others:

I had a view with 3 textviews with default values receiving values from a webservices from "doInBackground" method of a AsyncTask and later changing the text in them on "onPostExecute" method. The issue was that only one of the three textviews was showing the new text from the ws in the first execution of code (it's a simple application implementing the Zxing barcode reader reading a barcode from a product and obtaining the price from a webserver, anyway), the next executions (after the app is opened) was updating the three textviews normally.

So I noticed that the only textview that was updating its value in the first execution had its parameter "android:textIsSelectable" = true, the other two was false. Bingo, changing this parameter to true in the other 2 textviews solved the issue.