# permissions required to be declared in manifest for code

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask, manifest

i need to know the changes needed to be made in the manifest file
and what permissions are required to make this app run 
and also my intention is to get the strings from a web page and to display it inside "onPostExecute()"

```
package com.example.guru;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

//new code


class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

@Override
// username, password, message, mobile
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    // constants
    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
    int timeoutConnection = 5000;

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0]);

    try {
        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
            return null;
        }

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }

        line = total.toString();
        return line;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // do something with result

    System.out.println(result);


}
}


//new code end
```

Comment: will the system.out.println(result): work over here?

Comment: No not for android put a TextView and set the text using `setText()`

Comment: //would this be ok?<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/result />

Comment: check updated answere

Comment: possible duplicate of [AsyncTask OnPostExecute not updating TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680631/asynctask-onpostexecute-not-updating-textview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Permission to you manifest file

After

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.photon.filnobep"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="400"
    android:versionName="4.0.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

Or add from GUI

[image]

### Update :1

Add this to your layouts xml file

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="7pt" />
```

and the following in your activity class

#### Create a global variable

```
TextView textVw = null;
```

#### Do this in **onCreateView**

```
textVw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLike);
```

#### then this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // do something with result


     textVw.setText(result);

}
```

Comment: yup permissions are ok now. but seems the calling the newRequest activity is wrong?

Comment: result is a string that would be updated due to the background process, how do i display it thats the question

Comment: @N0062eclipse check my answer now and also not just copy paste the answer do replace with your scenario

Comment: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type RequestTask

Comment: Yes it is not available in AsynchTask

Comment: does the activity class(onRequest) also need another oncreate method??? i already have a main activity that calls this activity class onRequest

Comment: @N0062eclipse No; this onCreate method is your onCreate method of your activity class;
please paste your code for activity class so it could be more clear

Comment: cant i call an async task using intents?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

 />
```

Comment: still not able to run as i hoped it to

Comment: @N0062eclipse paste on your question rather than here